# Invalid ipa file: info.plist is missing CFBundleName error showing when upload ipa file on diawi

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipa

When I run my project on devices it's working fine.
Then I have created a .ipa build for development profile and try to upload on diawi.
But this above error is showing-[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFYFt.png)

First time I've seen this error.
Please can anyone tell me what is my fault and assist me what should I do now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Check your info.plist-> Bundle name set like the picture.

If its already set up correctly then check your Project Build Settings->Packaging->Product Name

Hope this help.

Comment: Great @evana.It has been resolved.Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

For This....
change your app version and Build version

go to general settings

version : 1.1
Build  : 1.0

hope it will work defenitly